# UEFI BOOTLOADER with MBR Drive

Tags: bootloader, mbr, uefi

I turned on my laptop today and it started saying "BOOT Device not found Error 03F0 Hard Disk", I checked my BIOS Setup and it was in UEFI Mode, I tried to boot from CD/DVD in UEFI mode and got same message again.

So what I did!! I changed the mode to LEGACY and successfully booted my device and installed Win8. But after that My HP Envy M6 1188 is taking 3 to 4 minutes to load Win 8.
So summing it up, On legacy mode, eveything is working fine except Win Loading Time.
But if i choose UEFI Mode again, That black screen with same message appears again.

I have MBR Drive. I tried Bootrec.exe /fixmbr and all other commands that i found through searching on google but all in vain.

I am still in legacy mode but i think win 8 will work faster in UEFI Mode.
I tried that EFI partition method but command said i have to convert my drive to GPT etc
But i am wondering, my laptop was working fine a week ago with MBR drive and on UEFI Mode On.
Any Suggestions!!!?
DO I really have to convert my drive to GPT?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. UEFI requires GPT to boot. Try downloading Partition Wizard bootable media and burn it to a CD, DVD, or flash drive. http://partitionwizard.com/bootable-flash-drive.html

It doesn't take long to complete the conversion.

Click here for a video on converting the drive to GPT: http://partitionwizard.com/video-help/convert-mbr-disk-to-gpt-disk/convert-mbr-disk-to-gpt-disk.html